# Is the $ϵ,δ$ definition of a limit not well-defined?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, soft-question

I just watched this youtube video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4eAyn-oK4M

He lays out his objections against the $ϵ,δ$ definition around 14 min.

Here is the discription of the video:

> In this video we aim to give a precise and simpler definition for what
>   it means to say that: a rational polynumber on-sequence p(n) has a
>   limit A, for some rational number A. Our definition is both much
>   simpler and more logical than the usual epsilon -delta definition
>   found in calculus texts. What is required is that we need to find two
>   natural numbers: k called the scale, and m called the start that allow
>   us to bound in a pretty simple way the difference between p(n) and A.
>
> The epsilon-delta definition of a limit is usually considered a high
>   point of logical rigour. Not so. It is also considered too logically
>   involving to be taken seriously as a pedagogical pillar for most
>   undergrads. Hence students may be told about the definition, but are
>   not required to seriously understand it, or be able to use it--unless
>   they are prospective maths majors.
>
> There is a subtle ambiguity in the definition: given an epsilon we are
>   supposed to demonstrate there is a delta (with certain properties) but
>   how are we to do this, since an potential infinity of epsilons are
>   involved? In practice what is required is a correspondence
>   (function/relation etc) between epsilon and delta but the nature of
>   this required correspondence is not clear. We return to our familiar
>   conundrum of using the work``function'' without a proper definition of
>   it.
>
> The key point that makes our simpler more intuitive notion of limit of
>   a sequence work is that we are dealing with very particular and
>   clearly defined on-sequences: those generated by a rationl polynumber.
>   A good example of the benefits of being careful rather than casual
>   when dealing with the foundations of analysis!

My question is: Is this an opinion shared by more mathematicians ? I kind a feel like that this Professor of the University of New South Wales is standing completely alone as it comes to this. I don't really undestand his objections, but I don't think I'm skilled enough to understand if his objections are legit.

Comment: There is no ambiguity in $\epsilon-\delta$.

Comment: We don't have to find a $\delta$ --- we just have to demonstrate that one exists!

Comment: He seems to think that we have to come up with an assignment $\varepsilon \mapsto \delta$... not so.

Comment: And with the axiom of choice, such a function exists.

Comment: @user1: Yep. But we don't need the axiom of choice to make sense of the $\varepsilon\delta$ definition of continuity.

Comment: 19.08 on the clock on the Youtube Clip

1. A sequence in a set $A$ is a function $s:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow A$??

Comment: what exactly is the problem in your 2nd-to-last paragraph? In math, we work with "infinities" on a regular basis; it is true that we can not explicitly *procure* them (as that would take an infinite amount of time) but we certainly may refer to them and describe them. Consider an infinite sequence or sum which we describe by a formula. So too here, $\delta$ will usually depend on $\epsilon$, and so we may describe an infinite amount of $\delta$s by one formula.

Comment: That's [the same guy who said that infinite sets don't exist](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356264/infinite-sets-dont-exist). Of course he will have a problem with $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definitions.

Comment: *It is also considered too logically involving to be taken seriously as a pedagogical pillar for most undergrads.*  It's hard not to read this as "undergrads are too dumb to understand that." I think that is manifestly wrong: they *can* understand it. The definition is both transparent and accessible. I do not claim that it is obvious or that an untrained person should understand it immediately, I just mean that in a reasonable amount of time anyone can be convinced it captures the intuitive meaning. I would take things this prof says with a grain of salt.

Comment: There seems to be a [discussion at xkcd](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=72537) about this individual, if I have not made some gross mistake.

Comment: @rschwieb: This fellow is a bit of a loon, but to many undergraduates the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity is anything but transparent, and in many calculus courses it is discussed briefly or not at all.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott As I said, *not obvious or immediately understood*, referring to the segment of students grappling with limits (and I gather, the segment you are thinking of.) For a student who "gets" what a limit is, it is hard to imagine a logical definition which is more transparent, (but you might surprise me ?). In case it is still slipping by, I'll reemphasize that I am definitely not saying (and didn't say) that the definition is simple or easy to learn/teach to anybody.

Comment: @rschwieb: You greatly underestimate its difficulty for many students. $\forall\exists\forall$ statements are inherently complicated, and the right-to-left formulation causes more difficulty. That’s one of the reasons people have experimented with other approaches, among them non-standard calculus (Keisler) and nearness (Cameron, Hocking, & Naimpally), that allow an intuitively more natural ‘covariant’ definition.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think any reasonable person reading my last two comments will have to concede that I have gone out of my way to say that *it is not necessarily easy to learn*. I certainly did not understimate the difficulty for students, but I always seem to underestimate my ability to evoke such patronizing comments from you :/ At any rate, thanks for the references to nonstandard approaches... I'll have to take time to look at them.

Comment: Maybe "not easy" is not dramatic enough for some, but for me "not easy=hard".

Comment: @rschwieb: Seriously? For me there’s a long continuum between *easy* and *hard*, and *not easy* definitely does not equate to *hard*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If you put yourself in the shoes of an undergraduate, the "not easy=hard" equation holds. :) For the rest of us, we have enough experience with a range of problems to have more shades. If that was the cause of this prolonged exchange, then I apologize. I just meant to convey the definition isn't trivial to understand, not that it is "slightly harder than easy".